# Construct a Turing Machine that accepts the following language

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

Give the Turing machine transition table for a TM that accepts the language:
$\{x ∈ \{0, 1\}^∗| \text{x begins with 0 and has as many 1 to 0 transitions as 0 to 1 transitions}\}$

Attempt:

Algorithm:

1)If it sees a 0 then move all the way down to the right until it finds a 1 and then keep moving right to find a 0.

2) Accept the string if the initial step is fulfilled

3) Repeat the same process.

[image]

Comment: I haven't checked your machine, but I suspect you can wildly simplify it. A string beginning with 0 has exactly as many 1-to-0 transitions as 0-to-1 transitions if and only if it also ends in a 0 - so, unless I'm mistaken, all you need to do is make a machine that accepts exactly strings that begin and end with 0.

Comment: Likewise a string beginning with 1 has exactly  0-to-1 transitions as 1-to-0 transitions if it also ends in a 1. Right?

Comment: Also, it looks to me like it's possible for your machine to accept even if the first bit is a 1, which isn't part of the language you're trying to recognize. I don't recognize the $\sqcup$ symbol, though, so I could be misreading.

Comment: Oh, I misread the language. I didn't notice that x begins with 0. That's why I do bad in the exams =(

Comment: It's worth noting that the language is regular, and that a DFA that accepts it has two states.

Comment: I updated the thread. How does that look?

Comment: Looks good now.  BTW, I was hasty in reading the language specification, and I overlooked the "start with 0" condition.  It is a regular language all right, but the minimum (complete) DFA has four states, not two.